# JavaScript -- передача кнопки, как элемента в переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

Когда событие происходит в кнопке, я могу её передать, как `this`, а когда событие происходит в `input`, как передать кнопку?

```
$("#button").bind("click", function() {
  $(this).remove(); // например, удалить кнопку из DOM
});

$("#input").bind("keyup", function() {
  // как тут удалить кнопку? $("#button").remove() не в счёт
});
```

Comment: Решение: `document.getElementById("button") == this`

Comment: Это же то же самое, что и `$("#button").remove()`, только чуть быстрее наверное; однако микс получается ... Хотя я jQuery не знаю, может так и <s>принято</s> допускается ПХТ; тем не менее, судя по [докам](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), можно сделать так например: https://jsfiddle.net/kapzk2n1/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Передать - никак. Но можно сохранить эту кнопку вначале в переменную и затем использовать:

```
var button = $("#button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).remove(); // например, удалить кнопку из DOM
});

$("#input").on("keyup", function() {
  button.remove();
});
```

Еще один вариант, [использовать функцию `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) и установить `this` или параметр по умолчанию для обработчика, но при этом потеряется связка `this==input` внутри обработчика:

```
var button = $("#button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).remove(); // например, удалить кнопку из DOM
});

var keyUpHandler = function() {
  // this === $("#button")
  this.remove();
}.bind(button);

$("#input").on("keyup", keyUpHandler);
```

Или

```
var button = $("#button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).remove(); // например, удалить кнопку из DOM
});

var keyUpHandler = function(btn) {
  // this === input
  btn.remove();
}.bind($("#input")[0],button);

$("#input").on("keyup", keyUpHandler);
```